How to engage in radical skeptical pondering for hours on a daily basis and maintain psychological well being?
I often have heard the sentiment most famously expressed by Russell that whilst practically all flavors of radical skepticism are unassailable, they are psychologically impossible to hold.
Recently, I have been engaging for long hours with such inquiries, in a small one window room, and it seems to me that I have made no progress in actually resolving the common philosophical issues (numerous issues from merely denying the existence of other minds to fully blown metaphysical solipsism).
Now, perhaps as a result of failing to make any progress whatsoever in addressing these problems, this form of obsessive skeptical inquiry has seeped into my non-philosophical work. I am a teacher of literature and now I am frequently casting into doubt the authenticities of the works of literature that I teach and read. Perhaps they have been fabricated or changed over time. I corroborate with many different editions particularly if it’s an old book.
I ask myself, “How can I know this author was even a real person?” For now I am managing to “snap myself back to ‘reality’" (?!), but I do fear what the consequences will be if I do not address this.
I have no intent on giving up this sort of philosophizing, and I was wondering if people have had similar experiences, and how they managed to both keep sanity and keep questioning.

Yo should read Sextus's Outlines of Pyrrhonism.

If you ponder a statistics textbook for a few hours a day instead for a few months, you'll soon be much more efficient at being radically skeptical.

"for long hours ... in a small one window room" Maybe you need more windows. More exercise, fresh air, healthy food, human contact. Psychology does not know many obvious ways a content of thought can corrupt (other than e.g. gaslighting/brainwashing), but there is plenty of research on compulsive behavior and drivers for depression. In any case the question seems off-topic for this forum.

+1 for @tkruse. Don't make yourself sick and then complain that you made yourself sick. I bet you Descartes and followers for a couple hundred years after, lived more wholesome lives than most of us moderns do in terms of sunshine fresh air, exercise, company. Until cars and tvs and so on came on the scene

I recommend you spend a few minutes on reviewing Descartes, eg.
One
Two
Three

If you can then try to reverse the question. Make psychological well-being your primary intention.

I ask myself “How can I know this author was even a real person?” Did Jesus exist as a historical person or is he a legend (a figure taken as historical although unverifiable)? All humans, real or imaginary, historical or legendary, are figures of our imagination! The biographical self is imaginary in memory. Authentication of evidence is linked almost exclusively to testimony of an expert opinion or witness: https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/fre/rule_901. We recognize testimony, witnesses, authentication problems, as a matter of folk psychology under the rules of law. Don't go crazy over it!

As long as you're not smoking pot and reading Marx you're good ;)

Consider looking in to Nonduality.

How to engage in radical skeptical pondering for hours on a daily basis and maintain psychological well being?

A question I sometimes ponder also.

I often have heard the sentiment most famously expressed by Russell that whilst practically all flavors of radical skepticism are unassailable, they are psychologically impossible to hold.

Meh.  I'm skeptical of that.  Maybe he just needed more practice???

Recently, I have been engaging for long hours with such inquiries, in a small one window room, and it seems to me that I have made no progress in actually resolving the common philosophical issues (numerous issues from merely denying the existence of other minds to fully blown metaphysical solipsism).

Been there.  57 days in Penetang which is max-security, despite my "crime" being unintentional contempt of court, by way of repeated failures to create and produce some obligated documentation.  Ooopsie.
Luckily my cell was the unit library.  Some 200+ random books that could be rotated from the central prison library.
Some 30 of the 57 days were spent in-cell for the whole day due to guard shortages (which coincidentally aligned a lot with sunny weather and long weekends).  Called "lockdown".  Having access to so many books was a huge relief.
Did a ton of reading, it was there I figured out why religions evolved into being within the human social structure.

You can see an example "one small window" through the door of the individual cells here:

I have no intent on giving up this sort of philosophizing, and I was wondering if people have had similar experiences, and how they managed to both keep sanity and keep questioning.

I would suggest it is conclusively so that your curiosity is a genetic predisposition.  Natural.

I would suggest, that naturaly genetic predispositions can be rationalized against (if that is a wish), or distracted from with other activity, or de-prioritized, put on the back burner.  Activity of the mind is typically a choice, to a degree.  (not completely)




skep·ti·cism   /ˈskeptəˌsiz(ə)m/  noun


a skeptical attitude; doubt as to the truth of something.


per Oxford Languages


Here is my answer, which is a question, or questions really, one skeptical guy to another skeptical individual...
PER:  maintain psychological well being

I am skeptical of human understanding of reality.  Why would I assume they have understanding of what "psychological well being" is, or looks like, or whether there even is such a thing?

Am I skeptical of all things?  Or am I skeptical of all things except the existence of "psychological well-being" and humans proper understanding and identification of what that is and looks like?


I knew a guy who made large coin, working in finance.  Hundreds of thousands a year in bonuses alone.  He also left for work at 4 in the morning, and got home late in the evening, many days of the year.  Clearly on a treadmill.  Belonged to a church and donated money, and... served on the board, until a disagreement about how to handle church finances... his way being superior, but rejected.  He quit that church.
What one considers "psychological well being" is vastly different from what some others might label "psychological well being".
So perhaps the answer to your question is... extend and exercise your skepticism of there being such a thing as "recognized psychological well being".
Maybe being different is the superior path?  Who judges?  Those who you are skeptical of?
Maybe spread those skeptical wings and be skeptical of the perhaps projected "psychological well being" model.
Perhaps.

There is a definition of wellbeing which fits with various forms of non-dual awareness. When one is not in conflict within the self, and hopefully not outside too, then it can emerge. This is a natural and expected development. It sounds to me as though you moved far along in that direction.

@ScottRowe I didn't mean to imply there is not psychological well being.  Merely pointing out that if one is to be skeptical of things, then one is reluctant to trust the opinions of others... and the existence of psychological well being, and what that looks like are the opinions of others... the same others who's other ideas we are skeptical of.  You see??

Sure. But I was referring to something one can learn for oneself. "Let go the things of which you are in doubt, for the things in which there is no doubt."

@ScottRowe If you can't believe in yourself, who can you believe in?

Absolutely. I believe myself only insofar as it seems justified, or I have no other choice, or... I just feel like it. Everyone else gets the same treatment, but without any help from internal validation. Wellbeing is a big help with all that. Look up the Center for the Study of Non-symbolic Consciousness. It seems useful.

An interesting question. Radical skepticism can be a strong ally, in my experience, to stoicism. Instead of seeing an excess of belief and an impossibility of knowledge as a bad thing, it becomes simple to accept things as they are because a agent of critical thinking cannot be responsible for that which it does not know. You may believe the author exists, but recognize you cannot truly prove it. So be it. That just means in that domain of discourse no one can truly know anything related to that fact, which means that you needn't worry about right and wrong, because given the sea of possibilities, it's likely everyone is wrong. And this can be extended to all domains: ethics, engineering, etc. You, then are free from the tyranny of having to be right, because there is nothing for certain. You are now free to be wrong as you see fit.


How to engage in radical skeptical pondering for hours on a daily basis and maintain psychological well being?

I can personally reassure you that Scepticism is psychologically unproblematic!
The reason is that reasonings are not emotions. Our reasonings involve emotions only to the extent that what we reason about is itself emotional.
In the case of reasoning about our absence of knowledge of the real world, this is unproblematic because humans, like all animals with a brain, use not knowledge but the beliefs they have about the world, to decide what to do next.
If anything, scepticism gives you a much more considered attitude about your own behaviour and actions, something that perhaps some people would do well copying.
You probably mistake scepticism with something else.
The sceptic believes that he doesn't know anything about the material world, not that his beliefs are crap.
Because (as I happen to believe), we don't know anything about the material world, we have to rely on our beliefs to survive in our environment. So, if our beliefs were crap, humanity would not exist. So, it is perfectly rational to trust our beliefs if we happen to believe that our beliefs help us survive in this world.
I also don't believe that there is any worldview more rational, and therefore more comfortable, psychologically and every which way, than scepticism.
Your choice. You believe what you please, including that you know (whatever).
Natural selection will sort out which is best for survival.
Although, maybe, this has already been decided.

If we're wrong, at least we're wrong in all the right ways :-)

@ScottRowe "we're wrong in all the right ways" If what we believe is true, though.


It can be hard, and I sincerely appreciate your sympathy for a poor sceptic like me. Please, if you can, can you make a small donation to my Personal Psycho-Philosophical Self-Reflective Welfare Fund? I assure you, I will use all proceeds only to combat my deep doubts that you are real! Don't you want to be real? BE REAL and convince a poor stump like me. Like Moore said, trying to refute solipsism, by holding up his hand:



This is my hand! It's real! It's there! I'm certain!



But as you well know, money talks louder (and I don't care about your invisible hand).

Seriously, there are big misconceptions about radical Pyrrhonist scepticism. The main one is that the sceptics make knowledge claims and must be entangling themselves in self-contradictions. But that's nonsense. When a sceptic says "There is no truth", this is not to be taken as an assertion, but rather as a provocative slogan - or as a not-too-serious-which-does-not-imply-disingenuous lament. When a sceptic, like Sextus Empiricus tells you their own story, it's just that: an autobiographical story about a search for truth and mental transquility that was (so far) inconclusive (at least for the truth part). But the sceptic is like the Greek painter Apelles who did not succeed in painting the foam on a wheezing horse's mouth. The painter finally gave up. In desperation he threw his painter's sponge at the unfinished picture, and - there it was! - a perfect depiction of foam. Similarly, the sceptic fortuitously happened to achieve a state of mental balance where the abstruse dilemmas and paradoxes of philosophy no longer disturb their peace of mind. -- And then may notice that most people actually don't live with any very special, elaborately worked-out "world views". Many "real" people, non-philosophers are sceptics. People who are still searching. Scepticism doesn't primarily mean "doubting", but rather "searching" - trying to keep an open mind, without pretense of having found the truth (with small or capital letter 't'). -- But it can be hard to keep an open mind.
For a generous, non-myopic account of radical scepticism, I recommend reading Arne Naess's study Scepticism (1968). This book was an eye-opener to me when I read it some 40 years ago. And somehow, quite fortuitously, it did happen to improve my dark moods. It's fine if the incessant search for truth sometimes stops, abruptly, since we're only finite creatures. Open a window. Take a walk through the woods.
Since you mention you teach literature, I also strongly recommend reading Zhuang-zi. (Burton Watson's and A.C Graham's translations are brilliant). Zhuang-zi presents a more humoristic, literary form of radical scepticism. He is often portrayed as a relativist, but it seems more appropriate to call him a relationist and to underline the similarities to Sextus.

Radical skepticism stimulates critical thinking and philosophical inquiry but too much skepticism is not good for mental heath. There are many things of which you may not be sure but there are things for which you must care in a certain manner.
For example - you must be sure about food and water. You must have a means of getting food and water without which you can not function. You are doing what you are doing to earn your bread and butter. That is the bottom line. Do not do anything which makes you mad or makes you loose your livelihood.
If you want to join the club of certainty then there are few, namely ,there are  physicist who believe that the speed of light is constant in vacuum independent of who measures it. Then there is a club of Buddhist Sangha who believes life and all conditioned phenomena are suffering. These subjects are beyond skepticism(at least for them). Find your faith. It can be scientific or religious or utilitarian.
If you still insist on doubting everything then may I suggest you some steps you can take to escape psychological trouble:
Have structured schedule ,practice mindfulness and meditation, do some physical activity, join social interactions etc

It is possible to escape from the trap of leaning on faith. Don't lean on anything or believe anything. Byron Katie said, "The only suffering is an unquestioned thought."


I often have heard the sentiment most famously expressed by Russell that whilst practically all flavors of radical skepticism are unassailable, they are psychologically impossible to hold.

Skepticism claims that we can't know much about the world. The claim that skepticism is unassailable is a result of adopting an extremely common but entirely irrational standard of knowledge: justificationism. Justificationism claims that knowledge must be justified: there must be arguments showing that an idea must be good or true or probable or something like that. If this was impossible then we would have no way of sorting true ideas from false ones, or so the story goes. However, every argument uses assumptions and rules about what follows from assumptions. But there is no way of guaranteeing or making probable the correctness of the assumptions or rules so justification is impossible. This argument is unanswerable because it is correct and there is no way around it.
However, as Karl Popper pointed out in "Realism and the Aim of Science" and in "On the sources of knowledge and of ignorance" in his book "Conjectures and Refutations", knowledge doesn't require justification. An argument explains that particular assumptions and rules would lead to a particular conclusion. As such, if  you find that conclusion isn't true then there is a problem with that argument. So knowledge can be assessed by looking for problems. We can guess solutions to problems and then criticise those solutions until only one is left and it has no known problems. Knowledge can be created by conjecture and criticism without justification.

Recently, I have been engaging for long hours with such inquiries, in a small one window room, and it seems to me that I have made no progress in actually resolving the common philosophical issues (numerous issues from merely denying the existence of other minds to fully blown metaphysical solipsism).

The idea of denying the existence of other minds only arises if you have to justify their existence. Since all attempts at justification fail, attempts to justify the existence of other minds is just a special example of the impossibility of justification. We know other minds exist because otherwise we have no explanation for the behaviour of other people. The theory of other minds solves a problem not solved by its competitors. The idea that other minds don't exist just takes our understanding of the motives and ideas of other people and arbitrarily labels them as false without solving any problems. Solipsism has a similar problem. See "The Fabric of Reality" by David Deutsch Chapter 4 for an explanation of this specific issue.
For more on non-justificationist epistemology, see
https://criticalfallibilism.com/introduction-to-critical-fallibilism/
and this Popper reading list
https://fallibleideas.com/books#popper
